# Add record in MS Dynamics fails: A property '_XX_value' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property [...] of type 'Edm.Guid'

Tags: dynamics-crm, dataverse

I`m trying to push data into MS Dynamics CRM via WebApi - in this cases 'productpricelevels':

```
REQUEST: >https://[SITE]/api/data/v9.2/productpricelevels<
METHOD : >POST<
Data   : 
{ "amount":124,
  "productnumber":"<EXISTING_PRODUCTNUMBER>",
  "_pricelevelid_value@odata.bind":"/pricelevels(<GUID>)"
}
(NB: This request is stripped down to solve this problem)
```

Result shows this error:

```
    code: '0x80048d19',
    message: "Error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity :'productpricelevels', For more information on this error please follow this help link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2195293  ---->  InnerException : Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A property '_pricelevelid_value' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value is declared to be of type 'Edm.Guid'. In OData, only navigation properties and named streams can be represented as properties without values.\r\n"
```

Metadata of productpricelevel has this:

```
    <Property Name="_pricelevelid_value" Type="Edm.Guid">
        <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.Description" String="Unique identifier of the price level associated with this price list." />
        <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.Computed" Bool="true" />
        <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.Permissions">
            <EnumMember>Org.OData.Core.V1.PermissionType/Read</EnumMember>
        </Annotation>
    </Property>
```

What is going wrong?

I followed the linked docs from Microsoft, but they have a slightly different error message and i did not understand their solution.

Simmilar questions here ended in replacing the key "_pricelevelid_value" by something different, but i can`t see the correct value.

Comment: Got it. Found the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543443/cannot-create-product-price-levels-when-creating-price-level?rq=2

This time, the correct keys are:

        "pricelevelid@odata.bind"    : `/pricelevels(${pricelevel.id})`,
        "productid@odata.bind"      : `/products(${product.id})`,
        "transactioncurrencyid@odata.bind": `/transactioncurrencies(${transactioncurrency.id})`,
        "uomid@odata.bind"            : `/uoms(${uom.id})`,

Comment: I would recommend checking XrmToolbox and Dataverse Restbuilder plugin for it. It saved hours and hours of my life so it could save some time for you as well.

Comment: by the way, "productnumber" is not valid for the Create message, probabily you are setting productid in the rest of the message

Comment: @AndrewButenko - Thanks for that - i`ll check it out;
@GuidoPreite - Maybe our system has some specialities. The field 'productnumer' really exists and contains the 'user defined product number'